# How to create a custom formatter for Faraday logging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, faraday

In the Gemfile, the gem is listed like this:

```rb
gem "faraday"
```

This leads to the installation of the current version 1.10.0.

Then, following [this documentation](https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/middleware/logger), I create a custom logger, but I get an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::Logging
Did you mean?  Logger
```

If open the Rails console and write the code `Faraday::Logging::Formatter` there, the error will be exactly the same.

Tell me, please, what is the matter and how to fix it?

**UPD.**

If I write this in the Rails console:

```rb
Faraday::Response::Logger::Formatter
```

Then I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::Response::Logger::Formatter
```

Then I write this:

```
Faraday::Logging::Formatter
```

And there are no more errors. What is going on?

```
bundle exec rails c

Faraday::Logging::Formatter
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::Logging

Faraday::Logging::Formatter
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::Logging

Faraday::Response::Logger::Formatter
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::Response::Logger::Formatter

Faraday::Logging::Formatter
=> Faraday::Logging::Formatter
```

Comment: What `faraday` version are you using?

Comment: Faraday::Logging::Formatter was added from 1.x, most likely you are on 0.x

Comment: @razvans `This leads to the installation of the current version 1.10.0.`

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Does `require 'faraday/logging/formatter'` in your console work?

Comment: @razvans This helped, thanks. Can I do something so that there is no double "require" and everything works through the console and as a normal running application?

Comment: Pull the your custom formatter class in a file and `require 'faraday/logging/formatter'` at the top. Then call your formatter class where you need it. You don't have to require multiple times.